# create NASA TLX in Google Forms

Tags: forms, google-forms

I try to build the NASA TLX in Google Forms, however the Scale Tool only allows for 10 values and if I do it via a Grid, there only fit 9 onto the page without scrolling as you can see in the image.

[image]

Is it possible to fix the given width that forms will make? Because I do have plenty of room left on the tablet the questionnaire will be given, however, forms fixes the width in representation...

Answer (score 0):

**Is it possible to fix the given width that forms will make?**

To the best of my knowledge, this is not a feature in Google Forms.